# Torch MNIST: How to fix bad argument #2 to 'v' (3D or 4D input tensor expected but got: [199 x 784]

Tags: lua, torch

I'm trying to modify the basic tutorial model here (http://rnduja.github.io/2015/10/13/torch-mnist/
) and to make a deeper model on Torch. Here is my code (The code worked when I tried the same model in above url):

Load data

```
require 'torch'
require 'nn'
require 'optim'
mnist = require 'mnist'
fullset = mnist.traindataset()
testset = mnist.testdataset()
trainset = {
    size = 50000,
    data = fullset.data[{{1,50000}}]:double(),
    label = fullset.label[{{1,50000}}]
}
validationset = {
    size = 10000,
    data = fullset.data[{{50001,60000}}]:double(),
    label = fullset.label[{{50001,60000}}]
}
```

Define network

```
model = nn.Sequential()
model:add(nn.Reshape(28*28))
model:add(nn.SpatialConvolution(1, 32, 3, 3))
model:add(nn.ReLU())
model:add(nn.SpatialConvolution(32, 32, 3, 3))
model:add(nn.ReLU())
model:add(nn.SpatialMaxPooling(2, 2, 2, 2))
-- model:add(nn.SpatialDropout(0.25))  -- Ignored for simplicity. 

-- model:add(nn.Reshape(12*12*32))
model:add(nn.View(12*12*32))  
model:add(nn.Linear(12*12*32, 128))
model:add(nn.ReLU())
-- model:add(nn.SpatialDropout(0.5))  -- Ignored for simplicity. 
model:add(nn.Linear(128, 10))
model:add(nn.SoftMax())
criterion = nn.ClassNLLCriterion()
```

Define the descent algorithm

```
sgd_params = {
   learningRate = 1e-2,
   learningRateDecay = 1e-4,
   weightDecay = 1e-3,
   momentum = 1e-4
}
x, dl_dx = model:getParameters()
step = function(batch_size)
    local current_loss = 0
    local count = 0
    local shuffle = torch.randperm(trainset.size)
    batch_size = batch_size or 200

    for t = 1,trainset.size,batch_size do
        -- setup inputs and targets for this mini-batch
        local size = math.min(t + batch_size - 1, trainset.size) - t
        local inputs = torch.Tensor(size, 28, 28)
        local targets = torch.Tensor(size)
        for i = 1,size do
            local input = trainset.data[shuffle[i+t]]
            local target = trainset.label[shuffle[i+t]]
            -- if target == 0 then target = 10 end
            inputs[i] = input
            targets[i] = target
        end
        targets:add(1)

        local feval = function(x_new)
            -- reset data
            if x ~= x_new then x:copy(x_new) end
            dl_dx:zero()

            -- perform mini-batch gradient descent
            local loss = criterion:forward(model:forward(inputs), targets)
            model:backward(inputs, criterion:backward(model.output, targets))

            return loss, dl_dx
        end

        _, fs = optim.sgd(feval, x, sgd_params)
        -- fs is a table containing value of the loss function
        -- (just 1 value for the SGD optimization)
        count = count + 1
        current_loss = current_loss + fs[1]
    end

    -- normalize loss
    return current_loss / count
end
eval = function(dataset, batch_size)
    local count = 0
    batch_size = batch_size or 200

    for i = 1,dataset.size,batch_size do
        local size = math.min(i + batch_size - 1, dataset.size) - i
        local inputs = dataset.data[{{i,i+size-1}}]
        local targets = dataset.label[{{i,i+size-1}}]:long()
        local outputs = model:forward(inputs)
        local _, indices = torch.max(outputs, 2)
        indices:add(-1)
        local guessed_right = indices:eq(targets):sum()
        count = count + guessed_right
    end

    return count / dataset.size
end
```

Train

```
max_iters = 30
do
    local last_accuracy = 0
    local decreasing = 0
    local threshold = 1 -- how many deacreasing epochs we allow
    for i = 1,max_iters do
        local loss = step()
        print(string.format('Epoch: %d Current loss: %4f', i, loss))
        local accuracy = eval(validationset)
        print(string.format('Accuracy on the validation set: %4f', accuracy))
        if accuracy < last_accuracy then
            if decreasing > threshold then break end
            decreasing = decreasing + 1
        else
            decreasing = 0
        end
        last_accuracy = accuracy
    end
end
```

and now I get the following error message when I ran Train part.

```
...s/username/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/Container.lua:67: 
In 2 module of nn.Sequential:
/Users/username/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/THNN.lua:110: bad argument #2 to 'v' (3D or 4D input tensor expected but got: [199 x 784] at /tmp/luarocks_nn-scm-1-2325/nn/lib/THNN/generic/SpatialConvolutionMM.c:33)
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'v'
    /Users/username/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/THNN.lua:110: in function 'SpatialConvolutionMM_updateOutput'
    ...go/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/SpatialConvolution.lua:79: in function <...go/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/SpatialConvolution.lua:76>
    [C]: in function 'xpcall'
    ...s/username/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/Container.lua:63: in function 'rethrowErrors'
    .../username/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/Sequential.lua:44: in function 'forward'
    [string "step = function(batch_size)..."]:27: in function 'opfunc'
    /Users/username/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/optim/sgd.lua:44: in function 'sgd'
    [string "step = function(batch_size)..."]:33: in function 'step'
    [string "do..."]:6: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'xpcall'
    ...rs/username/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/itorch/main.lua:210: in function <...rs/username/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/itorch/main.lua:174>
    ...rs/username/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/lzmq/poller.lua:75: in function 'poll'
    ...username/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/lzmq/impl/loop.lua:307: in function 'poll'
    ...username/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/lzmq/impl/loop.lua:325: in function 'sleep_ex'
    ...username/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/lzmq/impl/loop.lua:370: in function 'start'
    ...rs/username/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/itorch/main.lua:389: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'require'
    (command line):1: in main chunk
    [C]: at 0x0100c03350

WARNING: If you see a stack trace below, it doesn't point to the place where this error occurred. Please use only the one above.
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'error'
    ...s/username/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/Container.lua:67: in function 'rethrowErrors'
    .../username/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/Sequential.lua:44: in function 'forward'
    [string "step = function(batch_size)..."]:27: in function 'opfunc'
    /Users/username/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/optim/sgd.lua:44: in function 'sgd'
    [string "step = function(batch_size)..."]:33: in function 'step'
    [string "do..."]:6: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'xpcall'
    ...rs/username/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/itorch/main.lua:210: in function <...rs/username/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/itorch/main.lua:174>
    ...rs/username/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/lzmq/poller.lua:75: in function 'poll'
    ...username/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/lzmq/impl/loop.lua:307: in function 'poll'
    ...username/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/lzmq/impl/loop.lua:325: in function 'sleep_ex'
    ...username/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/lzmq/impl/loop.lua:370: in function 'start'
    ...rs/username/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/itorch/main.lua:389: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'require'
    (command line):1: in main chunk
    [C]: at 0x0100c03350
```

I tried to fix based on the solution here ([Torch mnist simple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37241970/torch-mnist-simple)) by adding `:view(1, 28, 28)` on the input data or by changing like from `inputs = torch.Tensor(size, 28, 28)` to `inputs = torch.Tensor(size, 1, 28, 28)`, however, they didn't solve the problem.

I don't understand what else I can try, and I am also still not sure how to debug this type of error. Thank you for your help.

Comment: The error occurred in the following sentence.
            local loss = criterion:forward(model:forward(inputs), targets)
However, when I checked the detail of inputs and targets, they were [torch.DoubleTensor of size 199x28x28] and [torch.DoubleTensor of size 199], not [199 x 784]....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found mistake at the model, didn’t need this sentence: `model:add(nn.Reshape(28*28))`. After commented out it, then got another error.

```
……./torch/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/THNN.lua:110: Need input of dimension 3 and input.size[0] == 1 but got input to be of shape: [199 x 28 x 28] at /tmp/luarocks_nn-scm-1-2325/nn/lib/THNN/generic/SpatialConvo‌​lutionMM.c:47
```

Then, found that Torch's target doesn't accept 0 for the classification, so needed to 10 instead. The followings helped.

https://github.com/torch/nn/issues/471

[Torch7 ClassNLLCriterion()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40046704/torch7-classnllcriterion)

http://nn.readthedocs.io/en/rtd/criterion/